# Changing the shape of arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, export-to-excel

I am running an experiment and I save all the variables I need in a array called `name.mat`. I save them all by assigning them to the variable results.

So responses are coded as `results.response`

I then type save name results and it saves all the assigned variables with the prefix results to an array.

I then want to write this to excel. However xlswrite doesn't seem to work unless all variables are on the same sheet where as mine are saved as different variables within the array results.

So I need to save the data in columns next to each other not start a new page with a new variable each time. I can then send that to xls no problems.

Comment: You should add a tag corresponding to the tools you are using (what is xlswrite? is it part of a library?). You can do that by editing your question (edit link below your question).

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you are using matlab? try struct2cell(results), and write the resulting cell array into excel with xlswrite.

alternatively, get the fieldnames of your structure array (results) with names = fieldnames(results), and iterate over the array names to access each field within results and write that into your excel.